# Can't install Fabrik - Warning: Install path does not exist

Tags: installation, fabrik

I'm new to Joomla (3) and not an expert in Linux (Ubuntu 18).

I have unzipped the package into 'factory_pkg' a folder in web-root.

Inside of it I have 'packages' and 'pkg_fabrik.xml'.

When I run Install from Folder and type

```
/var/www/html/factory_pkg/
```

the message says:

> ```
> Warning
> Install path does not exist.
> Package Install: There was an error installing an extension: mod_fabrik_form_3.9.zip
> ```

I couldn't find form for question in joomla website.

I got a script from Joomla 'Forum Post Assistant', it gave me this output:

> ```
> [quote="Forum Post Assistant (v1.4.9 (lambrusca) : 3rd September 2019"]
>     [quote="Problem Description :: "][size=85]I can't install fabrik package through folder [/size][/quote]
>     [quote="Log/Error Message :: "][size=85]Install path does not exist. Package Install: There was an error installing an extension: mod_fabrik_form_3.9.zip[/size][/quote]
>     [quote="Basic Environment ::"][size=85]
>         [b]Joomla! Instance :: [/b][color=Blue]Joomla! [b]3.9.11[/b]-Stable (Amani) 13-August-2019[/color]
>         [b]Joomla! Platform :: [/b] [color=Blue]Joomla Platform [b]13.1.0[/b]-Stable (Curiosity) 24-Apr-2013[/color]
>         [b]Joomla! Configured :: [/b][color=Green]Yes[/color] | Read-Only ([color=Green]644[/color]) | [b]Owner:[/b]  [color=orange]--protected--[/color] . (uid: 1/gid: 1) | [b]Group:[/b]  [color=orange]--protected--[/color]  (gid: 1) | [b]Valid For:[/b] 3.9
>         [b]Configuration Options :: Offline:[/b] false | [b]SEF:[/b] true | [b]SEF Suffix:[/b] false | [b]SEF ReWrite:[/b] false | [b].htaccess/web.config:[/b] [color=orange]No[/color] | [b]GZip:[/b] false | [b]Cache:[/b] false | [b]CacheTime:[/b] 15 | [b]CacheHandler:[/b] file | [b]CachePlatformPrefix:[/b] false | [b]FTP Layer:[/b] false | [b]Proxy:[/b] N/A | [b]LiveSite:[/b]  | [b]Session lifetime:[/b] 15 | [b]Session handler:[/b] database | [b]Shared sessions:[/b] false | [b]SSL:[/b] N/A | [b]Error Reporting:[/b] default | [b]Site Debug:[/b] false | [b]Language Debug:[/b] false | [b]Default Access:[/b] 1 | [b]Unicode Slugs:[/b] false | [b]dbConnection Type:[/b] mysqli | [b]PHP Supports J! 3.9.11: [/b][color=Green]Yes[/color] | [b]Database Supports J! 3.9.11: [/b][color=Green]Yes[/color] | [b]Database Credentials Present:[/b] [color=Green]Yes[/color] |
>
>         [b]Host Configuration :: OS:[/b] Linux |  [b]OS Version:[/b] 5.0.0-25-generic | [b]Technology:[/b] x86_64 | [b]Web Server:[/b] Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) | [b]Encoding:[/b] gzip, deflate | [b]Doc Root:[/b] [color=orange]--protected--[/color] | [b]System TMP Writable:[/b] [color=Green]Yes[/color] | [b]  Free Disk Space :[/b] 4.39 GiB |
>         [b]PHP Configuration :: Version:[/b] [b]7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2[/b] | [b]PHP API:[/b] [color=orange]apache2handler[/color] | [b]Session Path Writable:[/b] [color=Green]Yes[/color] | [b]Display Errors:[/b]  | [b]Error Reporting:[/b] 22527 | [b]Log Errors To:[/b]  | [b]Last Known Error:[/b]  | [b]Register Globals:[/b]  | [b]Magic Quotes:[/b]  | [b]Safe Mode:[/b]  | [b]Allow url fopen:[/b] 1 | [b]Open Base:[/b]  | [b]Uploads:[/b] 1 | [b]Max. Upload Size:[/b] 2M | [b]Max. POST Size:[/b] 8M | [b]Max. Input Time:[/b] 60 | [b]Max. Execution Time:[/b] 30 | [b]Memory Limit:[/b] 128M
>
>         [b]Database Configuration :: [/b] [b]Version:[/b] [b]5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-log[/b] (Client:mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 3591daad22de08524295e1bd073aceeff11e6579 $) | [b]Host:[/b]  [color=orange]--protected--[/color] ([color=orange]--protected--[/color]) | [b]default Collation:[/b] utf8_general_ci ([b]default Character Set:[/b] utf8) | [b]Database Size:[/b] 4.16 MiB | [b]#of Tables: [/b] 78[/size][/quote][quote="Detailed Environment ::"][size=85][b]PHP Extensions :: [/b]Core (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | date (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | [color=Green][b]libxml[/b][/color] (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | [color=Green][b]openssl[/b][/color] (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | pcre (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | [color=Green][b]zlib[/b][/color] (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | filter (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | hash (1.0) | Reflection (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | SPL (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | sodium (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | session (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | standard (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | [color=orange]apache2handler[/color] () | mysqlnd (mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 3591daad22de08524295e1bd073aceeff11e6579 $) | PDO (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | [color=Green][b]xml[/b][/color] (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | bz2 (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | calendar (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | ctype (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | [color=Green][b]curl[/b][/color] (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | dom (20031129) | [color=Green][b]mbstring[/b][/color] (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | fileinfo (1.0.5) | ftp (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | gd (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | gettext (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | [color=Green][b]iconv[/b][/color] (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | intl (1.1.0) | json (1.6.0) | ldap (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | exif (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | [color=Green][b]mysqli[/b][/color] (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | [color=Green][b]pdo_mysql[/b][/color] (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | Phar (2.0.2) | posix (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | readline (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | shmop (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | SimpleXML (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | sockets (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | ssh2 (1.1.2) | sysvmsg (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | sysvsem (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | sysvshm (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | tokenizer (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | wddx (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | xmlreader (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | xmlwriter (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | xsl (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | [color=Green][b]zip[/b][/color] (1.15.4) | Zend OPcache (7.2.19-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) | xdebug (2.6.0) | Zend Engine (3.2.0) |
>         [b]Potential Missing Extensions :: [/b]
>         [b]Disabled Functions :: [/b]pcntl_alarm | pcntl_fork | pcntl_waitpid | pcntl_wait | pcntl_wifexited | pcntl_wifstopped | pcntl_wifsignaled | pcntl_wifcontinued | pcntl_wexitstatus | pcntl_wtermsig | pcntl_wstopsig | pcntl_signal | pcntl_signal_get_handler | pcntl_signal_dispatch | pcntl_get_last_error | pcntl_strerror | pcntl_sigprocmask | pcntl_sigwaitinfo | pcntl_sigtimedwait | pcntl_exec | pcntl_getpriority | pcntl_setpriority | pcntl_async_signals |  |
>
>         [b]Switch User Environment[/b] [i](Experimental)[/i][b] :: PHP CGI:[/b] No | [b]Server SU:[/b] No |  [b]PHP SU:[/b] No |   [b]Custom SU (LiteSpeed/Cloud/Grid):[/b] Yes
>         [b]Potential Ownership Issues:[/b] [color=Green]No[/color]
>
>         [b]Apache Modules :: [/b]core | mod_so | mod_watchdog | http_core | mod_log_config | mod_logio | mod_version | mod_unixd | mod_access_compat | mod_alias | mod_auth_basic | mod_authn_core | mod_authn_file | mod_authz_core | mod_authz_host | mod_authz_user | mod_autoindex | [color=Green][b]mod_deflate[/b][/color] | mod_dir | mod_env | mod_filter | mod_mime | prefork | mod_negotiation | mod_php7 | mod_reqtimeout | [color=Green][b]mod_rewrite[/b][/color] | mod_setenvif | mod_status | Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) |
>         [b]Potential Missing Modules :: [/b][color=orange]mod_expires[/color] | [color=orange]mod_security[/color] | [color=orange]mod_evasive[/color] | [color=orange]mod_dosevasive[/color] | [color=orange]mod_ssl[/color] | [color=orange]mod_qos[/color] | [color=orange] mod_userdir[/color] |
>
>     [/size][/quote]
>     [quote="Folder Permissions ::"][size=85]
>         [b]Core Folders :: [/b]images/ (755) | components/ (755) | modules/ (755) | plugins/ (755) | language/ (755) | templates/ (755) | cache/ (755) | logs/ (---) | tmp/ (755) | administrator/components/ (755) | administrator/modules/ (755) | administrator/language/ (755) | administrator/templates/ (755) | administrator/logs/ (755) |
>
>         [b]Elevated Permissions[/b] [i](First 10)[/i][b] :: [/b][/size][/quote][quote="Database Information ::"][size=85][b]Database statistics :: [/b][b]Uptime:[/b] 13124 | [b]Threads:[/b] 1 | [b]Questions:[/b] 2815 | [b]Slow queries:[/b] 0 | [b]Opens:[/b] 557 | [b]Flush tables:[/b] 1 | [b]Open tables:[/b] 550 | [b]Queries per second avg:[/b] 0.214 |
>     [/size][/quote]
>     [quote="Extensions Discovered ::"][size=85]
>         [b]Components :: SITE :: [/b]
>         [b] Core :: [/b][color=Blue]com_mailto (3.0.0)  1 | com_wrapper (3.0.0)  1 | [/color]
>         [b]3rd Party:: [/b][color=Brown][/color]
>
>         [b]Components :: ADMIN :: [/b]
>         [b] Core :: [/b][color=Blue]com_users (3.0.0)  1 | com_login (3.0.0)  1 | com_newsfeeds (3.0.0)  1 | com_banners (3.0.0)  1 | com_postinstall (3.2.0)  1 | com_tags (3.1.0)  1 | com_media (3.0.0)  1 | com_messages (3.0.0)  1 | com_cpanel (3.0.0)  1 | com_modules (3.0.0)  1 | com_content (3.0.0)  1 | com_categories (3.0.0)  1 | com_privacy (3.9.0)  1 | com_ajax (3.2.0)  1 | com_config (3.0.0)  1 | com_checkin (3.0.0)  1 | com_actionlogs (3.9.0)  1 | com_templates (3.0.0)  1 | com_languages (3.0.0)  1 | com_contenthistory (3.2.0)  1 | com_fields (3.7.0)  1 | com_menus (3.0.0)  1 | com_joomlaupdate (3.6.2)  1 | com_finder (3.0.0)  1 | com_installer (3.0.0)  1 | com_redirect (3.0.0)  1 | com_plugins (3.0.0)  1 | com_cache (3.0.0)  1 | com_search (3.0.0)  1 | com_associations (3.7.0)  1 | com_admin (3.0.0)  1 | [/color]
>         [b]3rd Party:: [/b][color=Brown][/color]
>
>         [b]Modules :: SITE :: [/b]
>         [b] Core :: [/b][color=Blue]mod_tags_similar (3.1.0)  1 | mod_custom (3.0.0)  1 | mod_articles_archive (3.0.0)  1 | mod_articles_popular (3.0.0)  1 | mod_login (3.0.0)  1 | mod_related_items (3.0.0)  1 | mod_whosonline (3.0.0)  1 | mod_articles_categories (3.0.0)  1 | mod_languages (3.5.0)  1 | mod_articles_news (3.0.0)  1 | mod_menu (3.0.0)  1 | mod_random_image (3.0.0)  1 | mod_articles_category (3.0.0)  1 | mod_breadcrumbs (3.0.0)  1 | mod_articles_latest (3.0.0)  1 | mod_finder (3.0.0)  1 | mod_banners (3.0.0)  1 | mod_users_latest (3.0.0)  1 | mod_tags_popular (3.1.0)  1 | mod_feed (3.0.0)  1 | mod_wrapper (3.0.0)  1 | mod_stats (3.0.0)  1 | mod_syndicate (3.0.0)  1 | mod_footer (3.0.0)  1 | mod_search (3.0.0)  1 | [/color]
>         [b]3rd Party:: [/b][color=Brown][/color]
>
>         [b]Modules :: ADMIN :: [/b]
>         [b] Core :: [/b][color=Blue]mod_custom (3.0.0)  1 | mod_toolbar (3.0.0)  1 | mod_login (3.0.0)  1 | mod_title (3.0.0)  1 | mod_privacy_dashboard (3.9.0)  1 | mod_sampledata (3.8.0)  1 | mod_latest (3.0.0)  1 | mod_menu (3.0.0)  1 | mod_latestactions (3.9.0)  1 | mod_quickicon (3.0.0)  1 | mod_multilangstatus (3.0.0)  1 | mod_feed (3.0.0)  1 | mod_stats_admin (3.0.0)  1 | mod_submenu (3.0.0)  1 | mod_logged (3.0.0)  1 | mod_version (3.0.0)  1 | mod_popular (3.0.0)  1 | mod_status (3.0.0)  1 | [/color]
>         [b]3rd Party:: [/b][color=Brown][/color]
>
>         [b]Libraries :: [/b]
>         [b] Core :: [/b][color=Blue][/color]
>         [b]3rd Party:: [/b][color=Brown][/color]
>
>         [b]Plugins :: [/b]
>         [b] Core :: [/b][color=Blue]plg_captcha_recaptcha (3.4.0)  0 | plg_captcha_recaptcha_invisible (3.8)  0 | plg_user_joomla (3.0.0)  1 | plg_user_contactcreator (3.0.0)  0 | plg_user_profile (3.0.0)  0 | plg_user_terms (3.9.0)  0 | plg_authentication_joomla (3.0.0)  1 | plg_authentication_cookie (3.0.0)  1 | plg_authentication_ldap (3.0.0) 0 | plg_authentication_gmail (3.0.0)  0 | plg_finder_categories (3.0.0)  1 | plg_finder_contacts (3.0.0)  1 | plg_finder_tags (3.0.0)  1 | plg_finder_newsfeeds (3.0.0)  1 | plg_finder_content (3.0.0)  1 | plg_search_categories (3.0.0)  1 | plg_search_contacts (3.0.0)  1 | plg_search_tags (3.0.0)  1 | plg_search_newsfeeds (3.0.0)  1 | plg_search_content (3.0.0)  1 | plg_fields_user (3.7.0)  1 | plg_fields_sql (3.7.0)  1 | plg_fields_imagelist (3.7.0)  1 | plg_fields_text (3.7.0)  1 | plg_fields_usergrouplist (3.7.0)  1 | plg_fields_list (3.7.0)  1 | plg_fields_repeatable (3.9.0)  1 | plg_fields_editor (3.7.0)  1 | plg_fields_radio (3.7.0)  1 | plg_fields_media (3.7.0)  1 | plg_fields_color (3.7.0)  1 | plg_fields_checkboxes (3.7.0)  1 | plg_fields_textarea (3.7.0)  1 | plg_fields_url (3.7.0)  1 | plg_fields_integer (3.7.0)  1 | plg_fields_calendar (3.7.0)  1 | plg_editors-xtd_image (3.0.0)  1 | plg_editors-xtd_readmore (3.0.0)  1 | plg_editors-xtd_fields (3.7.0)  1 | plg_editors-xtd_article (3.0.0)  1 | plg_editors-xtd_pagebreak (3.0.0)  1 | plg_editors-xtd_menu (3.7.0)  1 | plg_editors-xtd_module (3.5.0)  1 | plg_privacy_actionlogs (3.9.0)  1 | plg_privacy_user (3.9.0)  1 | plg_privacy_message (3.9.0)  1 | plg_privacy_consents (3.9.0)  1 | plg_privacy_content (3.9.0)  1 | plg_quickicon_phpversioncheck (3.7.0)  1 | plg_quickicon_privacycheck (3.9.0)  1 | plg_quickicon_extensionupdate (3.0.0)  1 | plg_quickicon_joomlaupdate (3.0.0)  1 | plg_extension_joomla (3.0.0)  1 | PLG_SYSTEM_ACTIONLOGS (3.9.0)  1 | plg_system_log (3.0.0)  1 | plg_system_logrotation (3.9.0)  1 | plg_system_sessiongc (3.8.6)  1 | plg_system_updatenotification (3.5.0)  1 | plg_system_languagefilter (3.0.0)  0 | plg_system_languagecode (3.0.0)  0 | plg_system_fields (3.7.0)  1 | plg_system_debug (3.0.0)  1 | plg_system_remember (3.0.0) 1 | plg_system_sef (3.0.0)  1 | plg_system_cache (3.0.0)  0 | plg_system_highlight (3.0.0)  1 | plg_system_p3p (3.0.0)  0 | plg_system_stats (3.5.0)  1 | plg_system_privacyconsent (3.9.0)  0 | plg_system_redirect (3.0.0)  0 | plg_system_logout (3.0.0)  1 | PLG_ACTIONLOG_JOOMLA (3.9.0)  1 | plg_twofactorauth_yubikey (3.2.0)  0 | plg_twofactorauth_totp (3.2.0)  0 | plg_installer_packageinstaller (3.6.0)  1 | PLG_INSTALLER_FOLDERINSTALLER (3.6.0)  1 | PLG_INSTALLER_URLINSTALLER (3.6.0)  1 | plg_content_loadmodule (3.0.0) 1 | plg_content_emailcloak (3.0.0)  1 | plg_content_confirmconsent (3.9.0)  0 | plg_content_joomla (3.0.0)  1 | plg_content_finder (3.0.0)  0 | plg_content_fields (3.7.0)  1 | plg_content_pagebreak (3.0.0)  1 | plg_content_pagenavigation (3.0.0)  1 | plg_content_vote (3.0.0)  0 | [/color]
>         [b]3rd Party:: [/b][color=Brown]plg_editors_codemirror (5.40.0)  1 | plg_editors_tinymce (4.5.11)  1 | [/color]
>     [/size][/quote]
>     [quote="Templates Discovered ::"][size=85]
>         [b]Templates :: SITE :: [/b][color=Blue]beez3 (3.1.0)[/color]  1 | [color=Blue][b][u]protostar (1.0)[/u][/b][/color] 1 |
>         [b]Templates :: ADMIN :: [/b][color=Blue]hathor (3.0.0)[/color]  1 | [color=Blue][b][u]isis (1.0)[/u][/b][/color]  1 |
>     [/size][/quote]
> [/quote]
> ```

Can somebody guide to installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install the ZIP file through the backend of the website using the Joomla Installer.  
Go to Extensions->Manage->Install, then Upload Package File:
 https://share.getcloudapp.com/2Nu2pvbL

Comment: Actually, the whole mess was because I had wrong permissions on the folder and files. I made user and group www-data and permissions 755 on both folders and files (joomla root folder included). Then re-installed.